# Spring Restful Webservice to upload CSV

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I want to implement a Java Spring Restful Webservice to upload and process CSV files, then insert the records into DB.

As I am not expert in this side, I have tried several codes in order to build the web service and its client. But they all failed.

The last code I am currently using is:

for the web service class:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/file/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

And the client:

```
@Bean
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Client fileUpload = new Client () ;
        File file = new File("D:/hibernate.xml") ;
        //Upload the file
        fileUpload.executeMultiPartRequest("http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceMongoDB/rest/file/upload", 
                file, file.getName(), "File Uploaded :: Tulips.jpg") ;
  }


 public void executeMultiPartRequest(String urlString, File file, String fileName, String fileDescription) throws Exception 
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient() ;
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost (urlString) ;
        try
        {
            //Set various attributes 
            MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity () ;
            multiPartEntity.addPart("fileDescription", new StringBody(fileDescription != null ? fileDescription : "")) ;
            multiPartEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName != null ? fileName : file.getName())) ;

            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "application/octect-stream") ;
            //Prepare payload
            multiPartEntity.addPart("attachment", fileBody) ;

            //Set to request body
            postRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity) ;

            //Send request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest) ;

            //Verify response if any
            if (response != null)
            {
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace() ;
        }
    }
```

But I always receive the incorrect format or internal server errors.

I tried to use postman but I also get the below error:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
            <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
 org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
 org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:168)
 org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:90)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

The servlet-context.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->
 
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
 
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/**" location="/" />
 
    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
 
  
 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring.controller" />
 
</beans:beans>
```

[image]

and here is what I get if I try to run it

```html
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
 org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
 org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:187)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also, these code snippets appear to be deprecated and I couldn't find any new source codes or samples elaborating this part.

Any help?

Comment: Can you try executing the `REST` call using postman client? Also, can you share the stack trace of exception?

Comment: I have edited my post with postman response..

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it seems you haven't defined MultipartResolver. Can you try adding the following two bean definitions in one of your component classes?

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("500MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("500MB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}


@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Please note that `MaxFileSize` and `MaxRequestSize` will change depending upon configuration.

Comment: I was adding this tag to servlet-contxt.xml

  <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
 
         <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
 
    </beans:bean>
and now after adding your proposed methods, I get 
The type javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Can you please update the xml file and stack trace of new exception in question? thanks